Can someone help me understand the overall comorbidity in this OCD meta analysis?
I writing an essay regarding the prevalence of ocd in law students and I wanted to assess the overall comorbidity that ocd has
So I found a very good meta analysis regarding ocd and it's comorbidities but I can't understand the overall ratio. The analysis says that 69% of people with ocd have comorbidities and uses a sample of 16000 people. Then proceeds to list some common comorbidities like anxiety disorders with 32% prevalence etc. My question is, is that 32% based on the 69% of the sample or on the 100%. Here is the meta analysis for reference "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8631971/". So for example when it says that 32% of the sample has an anxiety disorder does it mean 32% of the 69% that has been been found to have at least one comorbidity or is it 32% of the overall sample of 16000?

Since Table 1 suggests there were more people with major depressive disorder than with any comorbidity the authors have quite a bit of explaining to do.

I just don't know what percentages to present in my essay. Like what percentage of ocd people have an anxiety disorder?  32% of 69% is far lower than 32% overall

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
